# Set user form border color property

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am using Excel 2016

I have a user form that works as a pop up menu with three buttons, the first and second run two different macros depending on which one the user clicks. The third is a Cancel button.

The Issue is that I want to be able to set the border colour of the form to match the Green colour of the Excel theme. The blue color that the user form defaults to clashes with the green and is frankly terrible.

Within the VBA editor I have tried setting the forms `BorderColor` to `&H00477422&` which as I understand is the correct code for the shade of green I would like. The little square preview box to the left of the `BorderColor` property turns to the correct color green but when I run the user form it has made no difference.

So I tried an initialize sub

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'this is the rgb code for the correct shade of green
UserForm.BorderColor = RGB(34, 116, 71)

End Sub
```

Which again makes no difference.

I forget how many variants I have tried this evening after now spending close to 5 hours on google and trying various suggestions that I have found but again, not a single one works.

So for the sake of my frazzled sanity I wonder is any one can tell me how to do what seems a very simple and obvious tweek.

I have to say that the default blue color is just so ugly.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

reset borderstyle.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With Me
        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
        .BorderColor = RGB(34, 116, 71)
    End With
End Sub
```